# How to remove empty expressions while formatting with clang-format?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is there an way to remove empty expressions (redundant semi-colons) like below using clang-format?

```cpp
int main() {
  return 0;
}; <- redundant ;
```

Naïve search-replace won't work due to other valid cases like below:

```cpp
struct A {
    int a;
}; <- required
```

Search for empty/expression/semi/colon gives nothing relevant on clang-format [docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

Comment: clang format is not responsible for fixing/improving code. It changes only formating (spaces, tabs, line endings, line wrapping), so can't add/remove none white characters.

Comment: You probably want clang-tidy rather that clang-format for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "[Bugprone suspicious semicolon](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone-suspicious-semicolon.html)" on clang-tidy but it does not pick up the case you provided.

clang-tidy will fix code for you given the right case. Example:

```cpp
# cat test.cpp
int main()
{
};
```

```sh
$ clang-tidy --fix  -checks=modernize* test.cpp --
1 warning generated.
test.cpp:1:5: warning: use a trailing return type for this function [modernize-use-trailing-return-type]
int main()
~~~ ^
auto       -> int
test.cpp:1:1: note: FIX-IT applied suggested code changes
int main()
^
test.cpp:1:11: note: FIX-IT applied suggested code changes
int main()
          ^
clang-tidy applied 2 of 2 suggested fixes.
```

Then the code is fixed in-place

```cpp
$ cat test.cpp
auto main() -> int
{
};
```

One solution would be to improve that case by modifying clang tooling

[Extending clang tooling](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/exploring-clang-tooling-part-1-extending-clang-tidy/)